# .Plot data from many files in different output files using do loop in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot 4.6.
I have many data files named data_1.dat, data_2.dat,...,data_100.dat. Now I want to plot data from file 'data_i.dat' to file 'figure_i.eps'. Of course I can do this sequentially for every file data_i.dat like this:

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color
set out 'figure_i.eps'
pl 'data_i.dat'
set out
set term wxt
```

If the number of files is too large, this is not a good method. I know that it is possible to use 'do' command in gnuplot 4.6. Hence something like following could perhaps be done:

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color
do for [i=1:100] {
set out 'figure_i.eps'
pl 'data_i.dat'
set out
}
set term wxt
```

However, I don't know how do really specify input and output files inside the loop such that correct numbers will be picked up automatically. Any advice is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use sprintf inside your loop:

```
...
outFile=sprintf("figure_%d.eps", i)
dataFile=sprintf("data_%d.dat", i)
set output outFile
plot dataFile ...
...
```